# C# Bulk insert from text file into SQL with multiple lins

Tags: c#, sql

So what I am trying to do is pretty different I'm trying to insert a set of part numbers in a text file in this format.

```
NTM-120
NTM-130
NTM-140
NTM-150
NTM-160
NTM-170
NTM-180
NTM-190
NTM-200
NTM-210
```

The insert data is going to be the same for all of the parts and here is how I currently do it for a single insert.

```
            //Inserts Feature 1 

            SqlConnection sqlCon2 = new SqlConnection("REMOVED");
            SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Products].[Features] ([ProductID] ,[Title] ,[ViewOrder]) VALUES ('" + textBox15.Text + "', '" + textBox19.Text + "', NULL) ";
            sqlCmd2.Connection = sqlCon2;


            sqlCon2.Open();
            sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlCon2.Close();


            //Inserts Feature 2 

            SqlConnection sqlCon3 = new SqlConnection("REMOVED");
            SqlCommand sqlCmd3 = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCmd3.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Products].[Features] ([ProductID] ,[Title] ,[ViewOrder]) VALUES ('" + textBox15.Text + "', '" + textBox20.Text + "', NULL) ";
            sqlCmd3.Connection = sqlCon3;
```

My main goal is to so select a text file and have it insert the same data from certain textbox (features) for each of the parts in the textbox, and the partnumbers must be inserted into a column as well they are the productID.

Is this possible?

Please help thanks. :D

Comment: I don´t fully understand your problem.. but why aren´t you using a parametrized query?

Comment: I'm trying to insert the same data for different part numbers.

Comment: Ok, let's try to clarify your question.. you are inserting from a text file (so why you have textboxes in your code?) into a SQL db? and your main problem is where?

Comment: You might want to use the BulkCopy class -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I want to insert into 1 column the partnumbers and the other columns to have the same data for each part in the same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand how to use a file in your question, but if you want to add many value of textbox in the same article (textbox15) you can do this

```
List<TextBox> texts = new List<TextBox> { textBox16, textBox17, textBox20 };
foreach (var textBox in texts)
{
   using (SqlConnection sqlCon2 = new SqlConnection("REMOVED"))
   {
       using (SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand {CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Products].[Features] ([ProductID] ,[Title] ,[ViewOrder]) VALUES ('" + textBox15.Text + "', '" + textBox.Text + "', NULL) ", Connection = sqlCon2})
        {
            sqlCon2.Open();
            sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
   }
}
```

**Update**

if you want insert the values existing in your textFile the NTM is you first part and 120 the second

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
   while (!sr.EndOfStream)
   {
       var readLine = sr.ReadLine();
       if (readLine != null)
       {
          string[] strings = readLine.Split('-');
          using (SqlConnection sqlCon2 = new SqlConnection("REMOVED"))
          {
             using (SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand { CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Products].[Features] ([ProductID] ,[Title] ,[ViewOrder]) VALUES ('" + strings[0] + "', '" + strings[1] + "', NULL) ", Connection = sqlCon2 })
             {
                sqlCon2.Open();
                sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
             }
           }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is something similar to what I need.  I need to be able to add multiple parts into the textbox and insert it

Comment: @user3324892 but a havent realy understand  your question ? what the relation of files and textbox !!

Comment: I think OP is loading the data from the file into textboxes???

Comment: @gbianchi but if the "-" seperate the values ?

Comment: @Akrem don't ask me, I'm clueless like you...

Comment: instead of using multiple textboxes can I just use a textbox with multiline and maybe do this for the part insert..NTM-120,
NTM-130,NTM-140,NTM-150

Comment: thank you but thats not what i am looking for.  Is there anyway to load a txt document into C# and in each line of the txt document have the part write into a different textbox from the text file.

Comment: @user3324892 ok, I hav answered in your Other question and test it (you can check if that you want)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> _partNumbers = File.ReadLines(@"Text File Path").ToList();
```

or

```
List<string> _partNumbers = File.ReadAllLines(@"Text File Path").ToList();
```

Traverse the `List` i.e `_partNumbers`, and insert them into the database.